# Firebase query on the basis of attribute exist(key)

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

> As I am trying to **short my data.** So I decided to save **userLikeCollection** as

`questionID = true/false` -> where `true means like and false means dislike`. And if this document not exist it means it is `neither like nor disliked`...

and there ID comprises of (**userID + questionID**)

Now I want to query whether this question is like by a user. Is there a way to achieve it.

```
db.collection("userLikeCollection").where(questionID ).exist()
```

or 
    read that document which has property string name questionID

```
db.collection("userLikeCollection").whereStringProperty(questionID).exist()
```

> where **userLikeDocument** look like below

(**userID + questionID**) -> Document Unique ID
       - questionID = true/false   //where questionID = any unique id for each document.

**Edit Question**

UserLikeDocument - 1

- blahblahQuestionIdOne = true;

UserLikeDocument - 2

- blahblahQuestionIdTwo = true;

UserLikeDocument - 3

- blahblahQuestionIdThree = true;

UserLikeDocument - 4

- blahblahQuestionIdFour = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to query whether this question is like by a user. Is there a way to achieve it.
>   db.collection("userLikeCollection").where(questionID ).exist()

Yes there is. To solve this, you should use a query and a `get()` call. In code it looks like this:

```
Query query = db.collection("userLikeCollection").whereEqualTo("questionID", true);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Boolean questionID = document.getBoolean("questionID");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In this code, the query will help you find all documents in which the `questionID` property will hold the value of `true` and the use of `document.exists()` will help find if that document actually exists.

> or read that document which has property string name questionID
>   db.collection("userLikeCollection").whereStringProperty(questionID).exist()

In this case you should also use a query but instead of passing a boolean value to the `whereEqualTo()` method, you should pass a literal String:

```
Query query = db.collection("userLikeCollection").whereEqualTo("questionID", id);
```

In which the `id` holds a value of type String which is the actual id of the question that you are looking for.

> (userID + questionID) -> Document Unique ID - questionID = true/false //where questionID = any unique id for each document.

This is actually possible in Firestore but only if the name of the properties are different, let's say `questionID` that holds a boolean value and and a `id` property that holds a String value. This can be done by chaining two `whereEqualTo()` call like this:

```
Query query = db.collection("userLikeCollection")
    .whereEqualTo("questionID", true)
    .whereEqualTo("id", id);
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> whereEqualTo("questionID", true) comes only if it is liked but when it is dislike .It will not retrieved

That's correct. To solve your problem, according to the official documentation regarding [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore **does not support** the following types of queries:

- > Queries with a **!=** clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example,
  >   although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported,
  >   you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with
  >   the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause
  >   where("age", ">", 30).

So with other words, there is no `!=` (not equal to) operator in Firestore. As they say, the option that you have is to split your query into a `greater-than` and a `less-than` query and then it will work perfectly fine.

You can also create another query that looks like this:

```
Query query = db.collection("userLikeCollection").whereEqualTo("questionID", false);
```

In this case, you get the question that have the `questionID` property false.

**Edit2:**

According to your edited question, there is no way in Firestore to filter documents based on a dynamic id. There is also no way to use wildcars. The properties should have the same name.

Comment: whereEqualTo("questionID", true) comes only if it is liked but when it is dislike .It will not retrieved

Comment: See my edited Question. Each document has unique questionID attribute

Comment: It means there is no way to get result on basis of attribute key.

Comment: No there is not. You cannot use dynamic property names. Please see again my updated answer.